# When image is captured using CapturePhotoAsync() OnAppearing get called on returning to the page Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to refresh my data whenever the app is resumed from the background. Actually, I want this functionality on only one page, not the whole app. I am using the Prism OnAppearning method in my model view. After capturing a photo with the camera when the control moves back to the app and OnApearning method is called again. How to avoid this situation? I tried OnSleep and OnResume in model view but these also have the same behavior.

I have attached my view model code below. **ClockInTriggered**
called when user wants to mark attendance with the face. **RecognizeUser** method get call for taking a picture from Camera. After taking picture method OnAppearning gets a call which is annoying.

```
   private async void ClockInTriggered()
    {
   

        string action = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet(AppResources.Select_Activity, AppResources.Cancel, null, Activities.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray());
        if (action == AppResources.Cancel || action == null)
            return;
        Activity SelectedRole = Activities.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == action);
       
        ClockInVisibility = false;
        LoadingIndicator = true;
        LoadingText = "";

        var recResult = await RecognizeUser();
        if (recResult == false)
        {
            ClockInVisibility = true;
            LoadingIndicator = false;
            return;
        }
        var locResult = await GetCurrentLocation();
        var revGeoResult = await GetReverseGeoLocation();

        LoadingText = AppResources.Done_;

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        if (recResult && locResult && revGeoResult)
        {
            Attendance attendance = new Attendance()
            {
                DateNTime = DateTime.Now,
                CheckType = "CheckIn",
                ActivityId = SelectedRole.Id,
                LocationInfo = ReverseGeoCoding,
                Lati = Lati,
                Longi = Longi
            };

            var result = await AddAttendanceEntry(attendance, "CheckIn");

            switch (result)
            {
                case "true":
                    List<Attendance> unsortedAttendance = await GetEmployeeStoredAttendance();
                    Attendance = unsortedAttendance.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateNTime).ToObservableCollection();
                    break;
                case "false":
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(AppResources.Error, AppResources.We_could_not_clock_you_in__Please_try_again_,
                        AppResources.OK);
                    ClockInVisibility = true;
                    LoadingIndicator = false;
                    return;
                default:
                    await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(AppResources.Error, result,
                        AppResources.OK);
                    await navigationService.NavigateAsync("/MasterLayout/NavigationPage/MainPage/TimeAttendance");
                    break;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            ClockInVisibility = true;
            LoadingIndicator = false;
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(AppResources.Error, AppResources.We_could_not_clock_you_in__It_can_be_due_to_location_or_face_detection_problem__Please_try_again_,
                AppResources.OK);
            return;
        }

        LoadingIndicator = false;
        TimeGradient1 = "#FFB75E";
        TimeGradient2 = "#DA2020";
        ClockOutVisibility = true;

    }


  private async Task<bool> RecognizeUser()
    {
      
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(AppResources.No_Camera, AppResources.No_camera_is_available_, AppResources.OK);
            return false;
        }
        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Small,
            CompressionQuality = 60,
            Directory = "Recognition",
            Name = DateTime.Now + "-Identify.jpg"
        });


        if (file == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        

       


        RecognitionResult = await Identify(file.GetStream());

        if (RecognitionResult.ReturnType == null)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(AppResources.Alert, RecognitionResult.Status, AppResources.OK);
            return false;
        }

       

        bool result = await GetCurrentLocation();

        return true;



    }

private async void RefreshLogAndButtons()
    {
        LoadingIndicator = true;
        LoadingText = AppResources.Loading___Please_Wait_;
        ClockInVisibility = false;
        ClockOutVisibility = false;
    
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        await GetCurrentLocation();
        await GetReverseGeoLocation();
    
    
        List<Attendance> unsortedAttendance = await GetEmployeeStoredAttendance();
        Attendance = unsortedAttendance.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateNTime).ToObservableCollection();
    
    
        if (Attendance.Count != 0 && Attendance != null)
        {
            ActivateButton();
            try
            {
                TotalTime = await TimeDifferenceCalculator(Attendance);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ClockInVisibility = true;
            LoadingIndicator = false;
        }
    }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
      
            RefreshLogAndButtons();
     }
    
    public void OnDisappearing()
    {
   
    }
```

Comment: How can we possibly help you when you do not post any of the relevant code?

Comment: @Jason please review again I updated the question.

Comment: `OnAppearing` is called when the page appears.  This is normal behavior.  You can easily add a bool flag to prevent `RefreshLogAndButtons` from being called multiple times

Comment: @Jason I did that it was perfectly working on Android but then I came to know that OnAppearing does not work on iOS. Very disappointing. So I changed my logic now.

Comment: *"So I changed my logic now."* Does this mean you got it to work? If so, consider adding "Your Answer" below, to show what changes you did, to get it to work. This would help others in the future.

Comment: It's a completely different logic according to my code flow. I discarded OnApearning. Not using it.